# How to auto-detect if a Git commit or rebase contains something like "<<<<< HEAD"?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-commit, git-pull

I recently made a stupid mistake of committing a code containing Git rebase messages, something like `<<<<< HEAD`.

I believe it happened because I `git add . ; git rebase --continue` without double-check if a file contains those messages.

I would like to know if there's anyway to prevent this? I mean, normally Git warns you when merging that there's messages like this.  But after you `git add .` I believe Git then treats those as part of my code?

I checked a famous tool called overcommit ( [bridage/overcommit](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) )
but there seems to be no such check.

**Edit:** in overcommit, there's this **PreCommit/MergeConflicts** hook, which only check my manual commits by `git commit`, but if it happens during a rebase, it won't trigger.

Hope I can find a real way to detect this.

Comment: I just briefly looked at the documentation for overcommit, and saw the [MergeConflicts](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/blob/master/lib/overcommit/hook/pre_commit/merge_conflicts.rb) pre-commit hook. Doesn't that do what you want?

Comment: Yes, I actually have it enabled.  But this happens in a rebase/merge operation, so the precommit hook is not triggered ( at least there's no warnings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<<<< HEAD` mark get added to file when there is a conflict.

So when you are rebasing a branch and git find some conflicting changes it marks it with tags

```
<<<<<<< HEAD 
conflicting changes in HEAD 
============ 
conflicting changes in current commit 
>>>>>>> commit SHA1
```

Whenever there is a conflict the git bash provides an indication by pausing the rebase and showing the exact commit number. You can either resolve the conflict manually or through a mergetool like kdiff3. Then you can do `git rebase --continue` to continue the rebase.

Let's look at an example

[image]

The above example has the following point

1. git bash detected a conflict while rebasing branch1 onto master
2. git provides help as to want could be next step
3. git pauses the rebase and shows at which point the rebase paused.

These are clear indication that your files are marked with conflict tags.

Here is the file at this points

[image]

So you have to go the file, find the marked tags, remove or add lines, save the file, git add it and type `git rebase --continue` to resolve.

In your case, you might have accidently left the `<<<<<<< HEAD` marker and continued with the rebase.

To avoid this, the best way is to use a merge tool like kdiff3. you can find the steps here
http://jebaird.com/2013/07/08/setting-up-kdiff3-as-the-default-merge-tool-for-git-on-windows.html

After you have installed and configured kdiff3, you just need type `git mergetool` in bash to open the kdiff3, whenever there are conflicts and resolved the conflict by simply selecting the parts you want. kdiff3 also provides functionality to jump to conflicting lines just by a click of a button.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is awesome, I solve all those conflicts by manually editing the file for years.  I searched all the mergetools and find vimdiff + fugitive.vim very useful.  Thanks for the help!